# get list of files to table format in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Could you please help me to get list of files to table format (I prefer batch file). For list command I would use dir /b /o:n to sort files by name.. but this produces paragraphs. I need to copy the list of files to xls table... and the files will be in columns. So my ask is this:

If you have files like 1,2,3,4,5... etc I want them to be written on one line, where tabulator is used as separator between files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Where tabulator (?) is used as separator" ???* If you want to open the file with Excel, then the simplest option is to use commas as a delimiter (.CSV format). Since a comma can appear in a file name, you want to enclose the names in quotes.

If you are sorting by name, then a simple FOR is your most efficient option, since it always sorts by name. You can use `<nul SET /P` to output each filename to a .CSV file without introducing a new line.

```
@echo off
<nul (
  for %%F in (*) do set /p =""%%F","
) >fileList.csv
```

If you really want to use the DIR command, then you need FOR /F. The only reason I can see to do so is if you want to change the sort order. I set `EOL=:` to guard against the unlikely possibility of a file name starting with a semicolon. A valid file name (or file path) can never start with a colon.

```
@echo off
<nul (
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o:n') do set /p =""%%F","
) >fileList.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I already found faster to use Insert "transpose" function in Open Office or Excel. I did not realized it before. Just to redirect dir to file and than, insert the data do column, and then copy them and insert with transpose. Note to your command. What does do the <nul ? I see it first time to be in begin of command and am surprised there is nothing on left side of the operator.

Comment: It is redirecting input to the nul device (disabling input) for everything within the parentheses. It is really only need for the SET /P command, but it is more efficient to do it once for the whole block than do do it for each loop iteration.

Comment: Why there are second quotes in the command set /p =""%%F"," I mean the quotes around %%F?

Comment: I want the output to be `"filename",` - but SET /P strips enclosing quotes. So I had to add an extra layer of quotes for SET /P to strip, leaving what I wanted. I don't have to worry about unquoted special characters in the name because FOR variable expansion does not need quotes or escapes.

Comment: The output must be quoted because commas are legal in file names, and you don't want a comma in the name to be confused with a column delimiter.