# Batch file to list file path and file name in a csv

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that lists all files in in a folder and sub directors and exports to a csv with file size, I curently have this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL

(FOR /f "delims=|" %%a  IN ('dir /s /b  /a-d') DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1-9*" %%x IN ('dir /b  /a-d /tc  "%%~a"^| C:\Windows\System32\findstr "^[0-9]"') DO (

        ECHO %%a, %%z
    )
))>DIR.csv
TYPE DIR.csv
```

But what I need is the File directory and File path as separate records

Comment: Please post a snippet of your current output and that same snippet modified to your desired output. Helps us understand what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a simple one liner directly from the command line - no batch required.

File names can contain comma, so they should be quoted in your CSV. The following will create a csv with file path, file name, file size on each line.

```
(for /r %F in (*) do @echo "%~dpF","%~nxF",%~zF) >dir.csv
```

Double up the percents if used within a batch script.

Type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command line for documentation on the FOR command. At the bottom is a description of all of the modifiers that can be used when expanding a FOR variable value.