# How to Extract Directory Tree and Files from XP into Spreadsheet

Tags: mysql, directory, export-to-excel, command-prompt, photos

How can I export the entire contents of an involved Windows XP directory tree into a spreadsheet or CSV? That is, how can I export the complete listing of the directory names, sub-dir names, file names, and maintain their hierarchical structure during export?

Below is a highly abbreviated representation of the directory tree I’m working with:

```
    C:\Dropbox\PROJECTNAME\Images\Photos
    .Sub1
    ..Sub1-A
    ...Sub1-A-1
    ....500+ photo files (JPEGs)
    .Sub2
    ..Sub2-A
    ...Sub2-A-1
    ....100+ photo files (JPEGs) [same for below directories]
    ...Sub2-A-2
    ...Sub2-A-3
    ..Sub2-B
    ...Sub2-B-1
    ...Sub2-B-2
    ...Sub2-B-3
    .Sub3
    ..100+ photos (JPEGs)
```

---

I’ve tried the following two methods:

```
    1) Browser
    1. Open Windows Explorer and select the source folder in the left pane.
    2. Press Ctrl + A to select all items in the right pane.
    3. Press and hold the Shift key, then right click on the selection.
    4. From the context menu, choose "Copy as Path".
    5. Paste the list into Excel.
```

It seems that this technique would work fine for one or two files that could be copied/pasted manually. But my directory is huge and complex and only going to grow more so over time. I’m therefore seeking a more comprehensive and long term solution that can be automated.

```
    2) Command Prompt
    1. type cmd into the start menu to bring up a dos prompt
    2. use the command (for instance)   "cd C:\Users\BobJones\Desktop\New folder" to navigate to the folder in question
    3. use the command "DIR > doggy.csv" to create a file named doggy.csv in the same directory that you can open directly with excel. Nothing much looks lik it is happening but you wuill find the small file as expected.
```

Same problem as the Browser method, really. The Excel files that were created only contained the corresponding XP directory’s immediate contents, and not ALL the contents down through the directory hierarchy. So, as far as I can tell, this would have to be performed multiple times, and then the resulting Excel files would have to be merged in some way. (The above Browser method seems like less steps, to me.)

Thanks, NewTo

---

This part of the question is addressed here: stackoverflow.com/questions/19184470/… – foxidrive

@foxidrive:
After much research, I’ve tried the following:

dir /s /b >filename.csv. This exports a complete list of filepath/filenames.ext, one per row of csv file. This is close to what I need. Is there a way to map each level of the filepath hierarchy into its own csv column/field, as opposed to one long string? That would get me where I’m trying to go.

I also researched the method at the link you posted. I was able to figure out the meaning of each part of the command, except for one thing, and please excuse my ignorance, but what does the letter ‘F’ mean? I assume it means ‘file’ (?). (In FOR /?, the letter ‘I’ is used to illustrate the modifiers.)

I tried the method at the link, with the following results:

1) for /r %f in (*) @echo “%~dpF”, “%~nxF”, %~zF >filename.csv  -returns-  ‘echo was unexpected at this time.’

2) (for /r %f in (*) @echo “%~dpf”, “%~nxf”, %~zf) >filename.csv  -returns-  ‘ “%~dpf” was unexpected at this time.’  [Parentheses aren’t indicated in the FOR /?. Are they required?]

NewTo

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please delete this question and ask the questions separately as you make progress with your problem.  This question is too big and too much all-over-the-place for the answers to be useful to anyone besides you; building a generally useful Q&A repository is what we are trying to do.

Comment: There's an easy method to create a CSV file with path,filename etc if you tell us what format you want in the CSV file.  Then you can ask a separate question to see how to get it into an SQL database.

Comment: This part of the question is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184470/batch-file-to-list-file-path-and-file-name-in-a-csv

Comment: @foxidrive: Question has been edited to address your response, thanks.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what format you want in the CSV file - which `field` contains which `data`.  The items 1) and 2) are missing a `DO` before the `@echo`

Comment: foxidrive: for /r %f in (*) do @echo “%~dpf”, “%~nxf”, %~zf >filename.csv.   This is creating a csv with the proper datum in each column, but for some reason it’s only returning the very last file in the entire dir/sub-dir tree, instead of all the files.

Comment: @foxidrive: Desired format would be: VertRes in col_I, HorizRes in col_H, Height in col_G, Width in col_F, filename.ext in col_E, parent sub-dir in col_D, parent sub-dir in col_C, parent sub-dir in col-B, remaining filepath prefix in col_A.

Comment: You need the surrounding parentheses as `2)` shows IE `(code)>file.txt` and your requirements for image properties will mean that either a VBS script or a third party tool (`irfanview` has the ability to extract many image properties from the command line) will be needed to get the extra properties that you don't see in a DIR listing.  Possibly `Powershell` also has the ability to gather properties.

Comment: @foxidrive: That worked. Thank you very much for your help. I will look into the resources you suggested.